# I want to use selenium to load more content on a website, but I can't find the address for the button

Tags: javascript, python, web-crawler

[image]
[image]
As you can see from the image above, there is a button on the page to load more comments. But I can't find the link corresponding to the button in the debugger. What can I do to simulate a click on this button using selenium?

Comment: Your screenshot cuts off the class names.... hard to help when we can not see the classes. But it will be a selector `li.discussionThread-showMore > a`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have modified my screenshot in my posting. When I use xpath and selenium to simulate clicks, the code gives an error that Element <a data-v-789a58f2="">...</a> is not clickable at point.

Comment: https://www.testim.io/blog/selenium-element-is-not-clickable-at-point/

Comment: Could you post link to this website, so we can have closer look to it?

Comment: https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/legion-solar-6-permission-free-energy-with-ai#/ This is the link to this website. I would appreciate it if you could check out the website in person!